# Is there a way to throw a link time error if a variable is initialized at declaration and linked to a NOLOAD section?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I have a variable initialized when declared that is also marked to be linked into a NOLOAD section, i.e. :

```
struct mystruct_s mystruct __attribute((section(".noload_sec"))) =
{
    .something = 100,
    .something_else = 100,
};
```

Is there a way for the linker to automatically detect this invalid condition? Meaning can we error if someone tries to initialize a variable at declaration which is located into a section which will not be loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few different attempts, and a lack of answers here, I've concluded that this cannot be enforced with current GCC.

A solution would be to write a build time script to scan the source and throw the error when a variable declaration for a symbol located in a no init section is initialized.